# Create Network Bridge that will allow me to access my home network externally

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, internet, home-networking

I am trying to create network bridge on Linux so I could access my network externally. I would Like some ideas? or pointers

Comment: That's something you do in your router.

Comment: I assume you mean a VPN or something like it, and there is a terminology issue here. You want to be able to access things on your home network when not at home from like a mobile computer or phone?